# How to replace quick launch menu with static menu in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to remove quick launch menu and

want to put my asp menu control which is as below.

```
 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Invoices" NavigateUrl="#">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Add New" NavigateUrl="~/CP/AddInvoice.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="View All" NavigateUrl="~/CP/ViewAllInvoice.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Manage">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Users">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Create User" NavigateUrl="~/Account/Register.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Manage User" NavigateUrl="~/CP/ManageUser.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="City" NavigateUrl="~/CP/City.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Customers">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Customer" NavigateUrl="~/CP/Customer.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Manage Customer" NavigateUrl="~/CP/ManageCustomer.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" NavigateUrl="~/CP/Products.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem> 
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Daily/Monthly Sales" NavigateUrl="~/Reports/DailyMonthly.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Monthly Average Report" NavigateUrl="~/Reports/MonthlyAverageWithChart.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Agent wise Sales Report" NavigateUrl="~/Reports/AgentWise.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

How can I do so,
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through [editing your Master Page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-a-master-page-to-brand-your-site-HA102449505.aspx)

Replace the content in `#s4-leftpanel` with your custom control and if you need to add any references for the control add them [just above the control code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58749/sp2013-adding-a-custom-usercontrol-to-masterpage-using-design-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove the quick navigation links and replace them with your links? Go to site actions>site settings and then under look and feel go to navigation, you can remove the current quick links there and replace them with your links. I think it's quite easier(less worries and less errors) than editing the master page.